Does Singapore Govt only accept Visa application before 30 days of travel date?
We are planning to travel to Singapore on 26th October to 2nd November from India. On many online visa platforms I read following statements:

We need to make a first entry within 30 days of Visa approval (MakeMyTrip)
Singapore Govt. only accepts visa application prior to 30 days of departure (Atlys)

If this is true, I will have to apply only after 26th September.
But the issue is, I have US visa appointment on 4th and 7th October, which will require physical passport and also it'll take around a week to ship the passport back to me.
So only option with me is apply after I get my passport back from US embassy around (15th October). Can anyone please confirm this? And help with work around if possible? Thanks. I have already booked non refundable singapore flights for Visa.

Good news: visa applications and the visas themselves for Singapore are entirely electronic, details at this page of the Singapore Consulate-General in Mumbai.
This means they do not need to keep your passport for processing, so there's nothing stopping you from applying for a Singapore visa first on Sep 26th before applying for your US visa in October.

This is not true. Unlike other countries, we can not individually apply for Singapore Visa, it needs an authorized agent to do so. All authorized agents here in India are requesting physical passport for verification. Check MakeMyTrip, Atlys, visa2fly, and even local agents.

@Kaushal28 That is not an official Singapore government requirement. In any case, while the agent may request that they check the passport on submission, they definitely do not need to hold onto it during the application process: there's no physical visa sticker, just an email.

@Iambshaanxy, it seem to be recommendation from Singapore Embassy and every agent online/offline requires physical passport to be sent to Singapore Embassy.

@Kaushal28 The consulate page above specifies a "photocopy of your passport biodata page", not the original.
